# Swift mailer default sender

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I'm trying to set a default sender to all messages in Swift Mailer 4.3.0, but couldn't find a proper solution. I want to avoid using ->setFrom() in every message, since it'll be a future headache. I could use a constant for that, but I was looking for a more elegant solution.

```
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
                ->setSubject('subject')
                ->setFrom(array('sender@domain.com' => 'Sender'))
                ->setTo(array('recipient@domain.com'))
                ->setBody('Message');
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.

As far as I know, you can't omit this parameter.

> A `From:` address is required and is set with the `setFrom()` method of the message. `From:` addresses specify who actually wrote the email, and usually who sent it.

This is maybe the best solution:

```
->setFrom(MyClass::FROM_EMAIL);
```

Once thing you can try, is to create an instance once in your application, and clone it when you want to send a new mail without re-defining the from part:

```
// somewhere early in your app
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setFrom(array('sender@domain.com' => 'Sender'));
```

And then, somewhere else:

```
$newMessage = clone $message;
$newMessage
    ->setSubject('subject')
    ->setTo(array('recipient@domain.com'))
    ->setBody('Message')
    ->send();
```

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid there's no such option when I looked into Swift_Mime_SimpleMessage. I'll try the clone approach for now.

Comment: Why do you need to clone? I think you can just use the same instance and change the subject, body, ...

Comment: I clone the original `$message` to avoid bad behavior if I have to send different mail. The case here, is I define `$message` somewhere in my app and then re-use it every where. (I agree it's not the best solution, but I guess that was my idea when I wrote it)

Answer (score 1):

If you use a SwiftMailer ≥ 4 and are familiar with [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/), you can use a [Defaults Plugin](https://github.com/Finesse/SwiftMailerDefaultsPlugin) for SwiftMailer to achieve this.

First install the package:

```
composer require finesse/swiftmailer-defaults-plugin
```

Second set up a `Swift_Mailer` instance:

```
$mailer = new Swift_Mailer(/* your transport here */);
$mailer->registerPlugin(new Finesse\SwiftMailerDefaultsPlugin\SwiftMailerDefaultsPlugin([
    'from' => ['sender@domain.com' => 'Sender']
]));
```

And then send emails without specifying the from address:

```
$mailer->send((new Swift_Message())
    ->setSubject('subject')
    ->setTo(array('recipient@domain.com'))
    ->setBody('Message'));
```